# do_action / add_action fired multiple times

Tags: wordpress

trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to insert a row into db while wordpress inits.

so, I'm doing:

```
<?php
add_action( 'demo_init', 'demo_do', 1 );
do_action( 'demo_init');

function demo_do(){
  # print(did_action( 'demo_init' )); # = 1 time called
  ### some more code ###
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->demo_log   = $wpdb->prefix . 'demo_log';
  $result = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->demo_log, array( 'date' => $event['date'], 'ip' => $event['ip']));
}
```

that gives me 2 - 4 records written of the same event.
tried to use 'init' / 'send_headers' hooks or global variables to count runs of the function, but everything applies that each run is unique...

could someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hook `init` directly:

```
function demo_do(){
  #Your function
}

add_action('init', 'demo_do');
```

Comment: I've already wrote in my question that I've tried that, and using `add_action('send_headers','demo_do');` with same result

Comment: Do you have any 404 showing up when you load your page? Ajax requests will also trigger `init`. Have a look at this question. Kinda same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372596/wordpress-why-is-the-init-hook-invoked-multiple-times

Comment: nope, no 404's, I've seen other questions regarding the issue and tried pretty much everything I've managed to dig up...