# How can I use a tool such as Live HTTP Headers or Firebug to diagnose a 404 error in my header?

Tags: wordpress, firebug

** Further Update **

I suspect my issue is something along the lines of a CSS background-url not being found (i.e. 404) or something similar. How would I use either Live HTTP Headers, Firebug (or another tool you may know of) to easily check this and identify the css url at fault? Thanks.

** Update **

These pages list the same issue as I'm having but unfortunately don't go into depth on how to diagnose it - they merely say to use Firebug or HTTP Live Headers - what I need to know is *how* do I use those tools to diagnose my issue

[Same issue as I'm having here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372596/wordpress-why-is-the-init-hook-invoked-multiple-times)

[Another one but not as detailed - only says Use the inspector in your browser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84082/action-hook-wp-firing-twice-why)

** END OF UPDATE ** ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW **

My site is based on Wordpress.

I've noticed that the 'init' hook is being called twice.

I've read that this is usually caused by an internal 404 error in the headers that are loaded that is normally caused by something like a css background URL image not being found or similar type of fault.

All I have seen during my research regarding curing this issue is to identify it using Firebug or Live HTTP Headers or other similar browser add on.

I have both Live HTTP headers and Firebug and I'm struggling with how to use these tools to diagnose my issue.

I wondered if someone could give me the steps needed to help me track this problem down.

Thanks.

Comment: You would need to diagnose the php code rather than diagnosing the HTML output (from browser) if it is a PHP header that is causing the issue...

Comment: what makes you think `init` is called twice? `init` is added by the wp function `do_action` and only using that function with the parameter would call it twice

Comment: @David I set up a bit of code in a function that is triggered once by init that emails me. When I refresh the page I receive 2 emails. I've seen this behaviour before so I'm sure this is the issue. I just need to know how to diagnose it. :-)

Comment: @RobertLee I have seen this behaviour before and it is normally due to a CSS background-url that is 404'ing or something like that. The fault does lie in the php code but I need a browser tool in order to show what isn't loading correctly. Thanks :-)

Comment: well if you use chrome/ firebug right click on a page element and "inspect element" and then console , you will see any page errors there...

Comment: @David I've clarified my question now. Please see above. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your issues are not html related, html is "client" side and php is server side so php finishes running on your server sends the information to your browser and then it will find the resources required (the urls)

`do_action` is a php wordpress hook, it basically means do all actions hooked here...

What the other answers are saying that if a page is not found, it will redirect to another page and hence you have two wp processes run to a point (http is stateless so each page refresh loads wordpress).

**You can use firebug to test http errors = right click on any page element, in the menu that appears, click inspect element and then in the new window click on console any http errors will be in red but only for the page loaded, but of course the page would not redirect because elements have not loaded, only if the page cannot be found. You can google firebird in firefox and you will find a install page for it.**

In the 2nd link there is the answer which i believe is the issue, if you have a issue at all. You visit the link once, a bot visits again anything hooked to init will run on both occasions, you might use `http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can` to make sure you verify the user before running the action.

If this is not the case de-activate all your plugins, install 2014 theme and try placing your action hook in the theme functions. It could be that someone used the code `do_action('init')` for whatever reason in one of your plugins or themes.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: thank you for the info and apologies for confusing client side / server side. I guess I'm asking how would I diagnose a CSS url that isn't found? (as the answer to this question would also lead me to find the answer to diagnosing other related issues). Thanks again.

Comment: its in bold above, if you have any images it cant find it will be in the console. If you want to solve those...inspect the element and see if the image is added via html or css (html will be inside img tags, css will be in the style on the right) you need to find where the image is being added. Check the url is it correct to the folder the image is in? etc etc! what is the site url and ill have a look?

Comment: Many thanks for your continued support. The site is just in development at the moment and is locked to my IP address in order to stop search engines etc from accessing it until it is ready to be ported to its proper domain. A big thank you for your offer of assistance though. There is nothing in red in the console area of Firebug. There's no other do_action('init') anywhere in the code. Although 'init' is being called twice. I'll continue to investigate and if I get to the bottom of it I'll return and post my findings. Thanks once again. :-)